# How to use jsonp callback of Twitter Api 1.1?

Tags: twitter, oauth, jsonp, twitter-oauth

Looking at the Twitter doc:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets 
I can use callback (optional) and it says "If supplied, the response will use the JSONP format with a callback of the given name. The usefulness of this parameter is somewhat diminished by the requirement of authentication for requests to this endpoint.

Example Values: processTweets"
 However, jsonp is using a script tag so there is no way to pass auth header in headers and Twitter is using oAuth. According to https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a I can pass data: oauth.authorize(request_data, token) as data to be authenticated but since I'm doing a "GET" I can't pass data as data but only as params. So I don't think this jsonp can work at all. Correct me if I'm wrong but is there any way to work with jsonp using Twitter api 1.1? Thanks.